# Find "singular expansion" of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I have the function $(1-z)^{-z}$, analytic except on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 1}$

Now in the text, it says the "singular expansion" at $z=1$ is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-z} + \log(1-z)+O((1-z)^{1/2})$

I'm not sure what, in general, a singular expansion is... it doesn't look like a laurent series.  Also, I'm unsure of how to calculate it, but I have verified through SAGE that this is the taylor expansion at 1... but I don't see how to use taylors formula to find this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(z) = (1-z)^{-z}$. We hence get that
$$\log(f(z)) = -z \log(1-z) = -\log(1-z) + (1-z) \log(1-z)$$
Hence, we have
$$f(z) = e^{-\log(1-z)} \cdot e^{(1-z)\log(1-z)} = \dfrac1{1-z}\left(1+(1-z) \log(1-z) + \dfrac{(1-z)^2 \log^2(1-z)}{2!} + \cdots\right)$$

Comment: Okay, I see it... thank you. Is there an algorithm for doing this in general? I'm not sure what motivated adding/subtracting log(1-z).

Comment: @David If only everything were algorithmic, mathematics would no longer be an art :). To answer you question, I do not know of an algorithm in general. Since, the expression has $z$ both in the base and exponent, I took log. Then I had to get the term $\dfrac1{1-z}$ and hence that motivated me to add and subtract $\log(1-z)$.